# Extract Residual Deviance from anova (glm) in R

Tags: r, extract, glm, anova

I fitted a glm model in R and took the anova table. I need to extract the "Residual Deviance" column. But it generates an error. Here are the codes:

Creating data:

```
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
```

Fitting GLM:

```
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = quasipoisson(link = "log"))
```

Anova table:

```
av.1=anova(glm.D93)
av.1
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: quasipoisson, link: log

Response: counts

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


          Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev
NULL                          8    10.5814
outcome    2   5.4523         6     5.1291
treatment  2   0.0000         4     5.1291
```

Now I need to extract "Resid. Dev" column. So I tried `str`

```
> str(av.1)
Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame':       3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Df        : int  NA 2 2
 $ Deviance  : num  NA 5.45 0
 $ Resid. Df : int  8 6 4
 $ Resid. Dev: num  10.58 5.13 5.13
 - attr(*, "heading")= chr "Analysis of Deviance Table\n\nModel: quasipoisson, link: log\n\nResponse: counts\n\nTerms added sequentially (first to last)\n\"| __truncated__
```

Finally I extracted `Resid. Dev` but it gives me an error:

```
> av.1$Resid. Dev
Error: unexpected symbol in "av.1$Resid. Dev"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use quotation marks

```
> av.1$"Resid. Dev"
[1] 10.581446  5.129141  5.129141
```

Equivalently

```
av.1[["Resid. Dev"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `[` operator to access the forth column:

```
av.1[,4]
```

Or if you want to use `$` qoute the column name:

```
av.1$`Resid. Dev`
av.1$"Resid. Dev"
```

Comment: or `av.1[,"Resid. Dev."]` (I prefer accessing by name wherever possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use unquoted spaces with the `$`, so use `[` instead:

```
>av.1["Resid. Dev"]
          Resid. Dev
NULL      10.5814459
outcome    5.1291411
treatment  5.1291411
```

Comment: yes, although you may want `av.1[["Resid. Dev"]]` instead (i.e. use double brackets to get a vector rather than a one-column data frame; the latter may be confusing).

Comment: And you can use spaces with `$`, as long as you quote the object name: ``av.1$`Resid. Dev` ``